# Make [k8s] a synonym for [kubernetes]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-process

I believe [k8s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/k8s), which at present has 62 questions, should be made a synonym for [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Makes sense; it's an unambiguous official abbreviation that users frequently use.

> [k8s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/k8s) will be removed from 62 questions
>
> [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) will be added to 18 questions
>
> A tag synonym mapping [k8s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/k8s) → [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) will be created.

Merged and synonymed.